# gcc link error occurred

Tags: gcc, linker

I compiled with gcc

> gcc -l. 'net-snmp-config --cflags'
>   -fPlC -shared -c -o matsu_object.o　tsu_object.c

but this error occurred

> gcc:  -lcrypto:  Because a link was
>   not completed, the input file of the
>   linker was not used

What's wrong?

Comment: net-snmp-config prints '-lcrypto' and GCC is warning you that it didn't use the library because it didn't do any linking.

Comment: --cflags doesn't print -lcrypto, you need --libs or similar for that.

Answer (score 3):

Did you mistype the question?  There's no way for that to output the message you write, and I would expect that the proper command is something more like

```
gcc -L. `net-snmp-config --cflags` -fPIC -shared -c -o matsu_object.o tsu_object.c
```

Notice the `-L` uppercase, backticks instead of single quotes, and upper-case `I` in `PIC`.

Also, you don't say what you're trying to do, but `net-snmp-config` should also take at least one of `--libs` or `--agent-libs` as well.

---

Ah, I didn't read closely enough...

`-c` means "compile", that is: generate from `tsu_object.c`, a compiled `matsu_object.o`.

Without `-c`, the compiler actually links, that is: generate from `*.o`, `a.out` or other specified file.

`-shared` (and linker flags like `-l` and `-L`) are only meaningful when linking.  They're meaningless when compiling, as you are doing here because of `-c`.

Please correct the command-line in the question to accurately reflect what you're running, and give some more explanation as to what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using ticks ' instead of back ticks `.  Does --cflags really give linker options?  I think you are at the link step here.  Also what is the effect of -c at a link.  I thought -c was compile only and not attempt to link.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the -c the first time I read the question.  It switches the compiler into compile-only mode (hence, no linking is done).  `net-snmp-config --cflags` doesn't give any linker options, so the command line in the question (even correcting for s/'/`/g) still can't possibly produce that output.

Answer (score -1):

You used single quotes instead of backquotes.

Instead of this:

```
gcc -l. 'net-snmp-config --cflags' -fPlC -shared -c -o matsu_object.o　tsu_object.c
```

You should type:

```
gcc -l. `net-snmp-config --cflags`-fPlC -shared -c -o matsu_object.o　tsu_object.c
```

net-snmp-config is a program. When you run it with --cflags, it evaluates to the correct cflags that you should be using to compile your program.

But you know what? You should be using autoconf. Even for something this small, it usually makes sense to do the work. Most people I know need to compile on more than one platform...